# Angular 2 FormGroups & Semantic UI error

Tags: angular, semantic-ui, angular2-forms

I'm utilizing Angular CLI with support for RC5 and I'm trying to utilize the [Semantic UI library](https://ng-semantic.herokuapp.com) and I'm trying to utilize their various form elements like `<input>` inside of my forms, utilizing FormGroups.

Here is my error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in ./SemanticInputComponent class SemanticInputComponent - inline template:0:19
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
    at DebugAppView._View_SemanticInputComponent0.detectChangesInternal (SemanticInputComponent.ngfactory.js:163:54)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64298:14)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64404:44)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64324:19)
    at DebugAppView._View_SubmitLinkComponent0.detectChangesInternal (SubmitLinkComponent.ngfactory.js:360:8)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64298:14)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64404:44)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64324:19)
    at DebugAppView._View_SubmitLinkComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (SubmitLinkComponent.ngfactory.js:37:8)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64298:14)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
```

Here is my form:

```
<form [formGroup]="submitLinkForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(submitLinkForm.value, submitLinkForm.valid)">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label>Title</label>
          <sm-input [control]="title" class="left" placeholder="Enter title..."></sm-input>
          <small [hidden]="submitLinkForm.controls.title.valid || (submitLinkForm.controls.title.pristine && !submitted)">
              Title is required
          </small>
        </li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
      </ul>
    </form>
```

Here is my component (simplified)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators } from '@angular/common';
import { REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-submit-link',
  templateUrl: './submit-link.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./submit-link.component.scss'],
  directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class SubmitLinkComponent implements OnInit {
  public submitLinkForm: FormGroup; // our model driven form
  public submitted: boolean; // keep track on whether form is submitted
  public events: any[] = []; // use later to display form changes

  constructor(
    private _fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.submitLinkForm = this._fb.group({
      title: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  onSubmit(data, isValid) {

    if (isValid) {}
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this issue? It seems to be related to the `[control]` attribute on the input field.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by needing to change the input field to the following:

`<sm-input [control]="submitLinkForm.controls.title" class="left" placeholder="Enter title..."></sm-input>`

It would appear that the [control] attribute needs to access the actual FormGroup's controls

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
  <small [hidden]="submitLinkForm.controls['title'].valid || (submitLinkForm.controls['title'].pristine && !submitted)">
          Title is required
      </small>
```